# boost::mutex, pthread_mutex_destroy failed - debug suggestions?

Tags: c++, boost, mutex

We have several locks (boost::mutex) in static classes, but when the program exits, pthread_mutex_destroy fails in the destructor of the mutex (there is an assertion checking this in boost).

As far as I know, pthread_mutex_destroy will only fail in two cases.

```
[EBUSY]  The implementation has detected an attempt to destroy the object referenced by mutex   while it is locked or referenced (for example, while being used in a pthread_cond_timedwait() or pthread_cond_wait()) by another thread.
[EINVAL] The value specified by mutex is invalid.
```

When I run in GDB and I print the lock I see that it is unlocked.
 Unfortunately I'm having trouble printing errno in GDB.

```
#3  0x000000000044a2c6 in ~mutex (this=0x847840, __in_chrg=<value optimized out>) at /usr/include/boost/thread/pthread/mutex.hpp:47
47              BOOST_VERIFY(!pthread_mutex_destroy(&m));
(gdb) p m
$1 = {__data = {__lock = 0, __count = 0, __owner = 0, __nusers = 4294967294, __kind = 0, __spins = 0, __list = {__prev = 0x0, 
      __next = 0x0}}, __size = '\000' <repeats 12 times>"\376, \377\377\377", '\000' <repeats 23 times>, __align = 0}
```

Now that I am writing this post the value of __nusers and __size look strange. This could hint to the lock being invalid, but I know that the lock was valid at some point (I wrap the boost::mutex in a Lock class, where I printed the value of this(0x847840) in the constructor, destructor and lock/unlock functions.

Any help as to how to debug this would be greatly appreciated.

**Edit**
The Locks class inherits from boost::mutex, and exports a scopedlock (from memory):

```
lock_type::scoped_lock getScopedLock() {
  return lock_type::scoped_lock( *this );
}
```

I've also tried to add the lock as a member, instead of inheriting from it, with no change in behavior.
I do not think that the getScopedLock function could introduce any problems(the scoped lock is returned y value, but a copy is not made because of RVO), but thought it could be worth mentioning.
It is used as follows (we are using c++0x):

```
auto lock = lock_.getScopedLock();
```

The complete stracktrace:

```
(gdb) where
#0  0x00007ffff559da75 in *__GI_raise (sig=<value optimized out>) at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:64
#1  0x00007ffff55a15c0 in *__GI_abort () at abort.c:92
#2  0x00007ffff5596941 in *__GI___assert_fail (assertion=0x55851c "!pthread_mutex_destroy(&m)", file=<value optimized out>, line=47, 
    function=0x5595a0 "boost::mutex::~mutex()") at assert.c:81
#3  0x000000000044a2c6 in ~mutex (this=0x847840, __in_chrg=<value optimized out>) at /usr/include/boost/thread/pthread/mutex.hpp:47
#4  0x000000000044d923 in ~Lock (this=0x847840, __in_chrg=<value optimized out>) at include/Locks.h:43
#5  0x00007ffff55a3262 in __run_exit_handlers (status=0) at exit.c:78
#6  *__GI_exit (status=0) at exit.c:100
#7  0x00000000004ea9a6 in start () at src/main.cc:191
#8  0x00000000004de5aa in main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffe7b8) at src/main.cc:90
```

Comment: Would help if you showed the code (for example whats going on in `Locks.h`)

Comment: There is very little code to post, which is one of the reasons why I made this post, because I don't know where in the thousands of lines of code to look for the problem. So unfortunately I cannot make a small testcase either. I don't even know which of the several locks is breaking (I could figure that out by printing the addresses of all the locks where I initializ them).All that the Locks class does is inherit from boost::mutex atm, it does nothig else.

Comment: @thelamb if you cannot post a reproducer, run your code under valgrind.

Comment: If `gdb` reports "Cannot find thread-local variables on this target" whenever you attempt to print `errno`, try linking with libpthread; pass `-lpthread` to the linker.

Comment: Please post your Lock class. Your use of RVO looks bad to me - I believe some compilers wont compile your code (because I believe scoped lock to be non-copiable). Also its completely unnecessary - what is wrong with typing `boost::mutex::scoped_lock l(lock_)` - I think your use of auto is unclear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You typically get this error when you `unlock` your mutex without locking it first.

```
  boost::mutex m;
  m.unlock();
```

My guess is that somewhere you are using `lock` and `unlock` members rather than `RAII`,
and that you have lost a call to `lock`.

Note that most of the time you should not be calling the `lock` and `unlock` members.  Use the `scoped_lock` which calls the functions for you.

```
struct s
{
  void foo()
  {
    boost::mutex::scoped_lock l(m_mutex);
    //do something
  }
  private: 
    boost::mutex m_mutex;
};
```

Also, you mention that you are inheriting from `boost::mutex`.  This can cause problems becuase `boost::mutex` does not have a virtual destructor, so its best not to do that.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I will check our use of lock and ulock. In most cases we use a scoped_lock already though. Your right about the inheritance being unsafe, but I checked already if I modify Lock to keep the mutex as a member and export the lock/unlock functions the problem persists. I will do this again and keep a variable to check whether unlock is called first and the state is still unlocked. I forgot to mention one thing about Lock, see my edited post

Comment: as to your concern about getScopedLock: I should mention we're using C++0x. Scoped locks are movable. But since no moving nor copying is involved here there should be no issue (I'm not overly concerned about it not working on other compilers).

Answer (score 3):

Ok turns out there were two problems.
There was one lock, which never got used but when stopping I did call unlock.
Obviously I didn't read the documentation correctly, as there is a precondition on unlock that the current thread must own lock. 
Thank you Tom for getting me to see this.

The second problem was that somewhere I have a scoped lock, and I want to unlock it before it goes out of scope:

```
auto lock = lock_.getScopedLock();
if( something )
   lock.unlock();
```

Originally, this read `lock_.unlock();`, so I was unlocking the mutex, not via the scoped lock.

@Tom, the reason I don't like writing `boost::mutex::scoped_lock l(lock_)` is that if you write `boost::mutex::scoped_lock l()` there will be no errors whatsoever.
Now, the only danger I see is that someone writes `lock_.getScopedLock()` without storing it in a variable, I guess when someone else starts touching the code we'd just define a macro for getting the scoped lock (yes yes, we could do the same for the variant without getScopedLock ;)).
In any case, I'm not inheriting from `boost::mutex` anymore, but instead keeping it as a member. You are right that we should not risk inheriting from it.

@Daniel,
Compiling with -lpthread did not help, I don't have time to look at that particular problem at the moment, as I don't need it, but thank you for your suggestion anyway.

@Sam,
I did run in valgrind, but it showed no interesting output to the lock problem.